# When the gradient $\nabla f$ is parallel to position vector $\textbf{r}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vectors, vector-analysis

I've got the below exercise in my textbook.

> Suppose that $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ is always parallel to the position
> vector $x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}+z\textbf{k}$. Show that
> $f(0,0,a)=f(0,0,-a)$ for any $a$.

Kindly see if my solution is correct.

**My Solution**.

Let $f(x,y,z)=0$ be the surface we're dealing with and $\textbf{r}(t)=x(t)\textbf{i}+y(t)\textbf{j}+z(t)\textbf{k}$ be the position vector where the variables are parameterized. It can be seen that
$$
f(\textbf{r}(t))=0 \implies \frac{df}{dt}=0
$$
Which gives us
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} =0
$$

which is basically saying
$$
\nabla f\cdot \textbf{r}'(t)=0 \tag{1}
$$

Since it is given that $\nabla f$ is always parallel to $\textbf{r}(t)$ it can be said that
$$
\nabla f =k\textbf{r}(t) \tag{2}
$$
where $k$ is a scalar quantity.

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$, we get
$$
k\textbf{r}(t)\cdot \textbf{r}'(t)=0 \implies \textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{r}'=0
$$

The only time above happens is when $\textbf{r}(t)$ is of constant magnitude, say $c$.
$$
\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{r}=|\textbf{r}|^2=c^2
$$
Differentiating which, we get the said result. This clearly means
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=c^2
$$

I'm not entirely sure how to use the above fact to get what's asked but here it goes:

Since $x$, $y$ and $z$ form a sphere, I can say (can i really?)
$$
f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-c^2
$$
Hence, $f(0,0,a)=f(0,0,-a)=a^2-c^2$

Comment: this can’t be right because if f is one such function, then so is g defined by $g(x,y,z)=f(2x,2y,2z)$. This means that $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-c^2$ cannot be all solutions

Comment: @CalvinKhor Gotcha. How about the conclusion "points $x$, $y$ and $z$ form the surface of a sphere and hence $f=0$ represents any sphere" and prove what's required?

Comment: I haven’t thought about it, sorry. I’m not sure what the relationship is with f=0. The result should be that f is radial. Indeed any radial function satisfies the assumption and conclusion.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got: “Using (2)
(
2
)
 in (1)
(
1
)
, we get
$()⋅′()=0⟹⋅′=0$”

Comment: @MathAndPhysics a non zero constant times a dot product is zero means the dot product is zero.

Comment: As I told you in my first comment above, no, you cannot say that $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2 - c^2$, so I already answered your recent edit